# Do all Eye drops for dry eyes contain steriods?

Tags: medications, treatment

Do all eye drops for the dry eyes contain steroid?
How can you check if the eye drops include steroids in it?

Answer (score 2):

Only some types of eye drops for dry eyes (artificial tears) contain steroids.

The information leaflet that comes with eye drops that contain steroids may or may not mention the term "steroids" or "corticosteroids" - and if not - it should certainly mention the exact steroid, for example:

- fluocinolone
- loteprednol
- dexamethasone
- fluorometholone
- prednisolone

For more examples check [**ophthalmic steroids** on drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/drug-class/ophthalmic-steroids.html).